# Why am I experiencing poor performance with Task.WhenAll, RestSharp, and Async-Await in API gateway?

Tags: c#, docker, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc, restsharp

I am writing a Search API that aggregates results from a number of microservice APIs using async-await and awaiting Task.WhenAll. At most, I make 11 microservice API calls per request to to the Search API. However, I'm seeing inconsistent performance - sometimes Search API takes 400 milliseconds (acceptable) and others it takes over a second (unacceptable), even when I run locally/without load. The bulk of the slowdown appears to be happening around await Task.WhenAll.

Three observations:

- Search API sometimes starts 1/3 or 1/2 of the calls to the microservice API's, then waits 600-1000ms to start the next bunch. This batching behavior is inconsistent.
- Search API sometimes calls out to each microservice API, gets results and waits for another 500-1000ms. For example, Search API might take 1000ms, all of the microservice requests start within 100ms of each other, and internally complete after 400ms or less. However, Search API just continues to sit on the WhenAll for another 500ms after responses are all sent back.
- This behavior is not consistent. If I run this 30 times, maybe 5 or 10 of them take super long relative to the other 25 or 20.

All API's are written in ASP.NET Core MVC, running in Linux Docker containers on a single docker network (should be local to each other), and are async.

In each of the API's, I am logging the duration of incoming requests so I have a complete picture of timing and duration throughout the request across applications.

**Steps I've tried**

- The http client is RestSharp, but I have tried replacing with .NET's HttpClient without any material difference.
- Tried using Parallel.ForEach which actually was slower.
- Tried changing the individual microservice API Controllers to not do any processing - just return a 200 with no body immediately - but still get that same behavior.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("get-something")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetSomethingAsync(int id)
{
    //search engine is a scoped dependency injected via DI
    return await _searchEngine.Search(id);
}
```

**SearchEngine**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Search(int id)
{
    //both clients are transient dependencies injected via DI
    var iceTasks = _iceClient.FetchTasksAsync(id).ToList();
    var fireTasks = _fireClient.FetchTasksAsync(id).ToList();

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(iceTasks.Union(fireTasks));

    return results.SelectMany(r => r.Data);
}
```

**IceClient and FireClient Base Class**

```
public List<Task<IRestResponse<IEnumerable<int>>>> FetchTasksAsync(int id)  
{
    var taskList = new List<Task<IRestResponse<IEnumerable<int>>>>();
    var restClient = new RestClient()
    {
        Timeout = 20000 //in ms
    };

    foreach (var url in _urlFactory.Create())
    {
        var task = restClient.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(new RestRequest(url));

        taskList.Add(task);
    }

    return taskList;
}
```

**Expectation**
Each of the API calls should be kicked off within 30 ms of each other and the total search duration is approximately the duration of the longest microservice API duration.

Comment: `WhenAll` won't cause that kind of overhead; there's something else going on. I'd recommend changing `await Task.WhenAll` to `foreach (var task in ...) await task;` and see which task it is that is slow.

Comment: Well the odd thing is I can repeat this same exact operation 30 times, and 5-10 will present this behavior. If it was a particularly slow task, would you expect it to be consistent?

Comment: Sounds like you've got something else interfering. I would expect odd slowdowns only under load: requests not being picked up because they're waiting in the request queue, or async methods seeing delays because the thread pool is saturated. But in a no-load situation, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: An `async` method does not return immediately if you don't `await` it. It will run (calling into inner methods) until it hits the first point where it would block, then the stack is unwound and you get a `Task` which you then add to the list and begin creating the next one. Use `Task.Run ()` in your `FetchTasksAsync` method to launch the subordinate tasks on the thread pool.

Comment: Would love to understand the downvotes here so I can improve my future questions.

Comment: This isn’t a complete answer, so adding as a comment. Iirc, there may have been some contention internal to the .NET HttpClient version I was using to test against RestSharp. I think MS released a new version shortly after I posted this, and it did actually improve some. Not recalling if it resolved the issue completely.